# How should I disable application logs into syslog?

Tags: linux, syslog, dmesg

I have many services that floods syslog file in `/var/log` with tons of messages. Sometime server restart all of a sudden and when I created a ticket about the issue, they said that the problem is related to the heavy use of the emulated serial port. By default, the emulated serial port receives the kernel log messages.

On my server `dmseg` is empty, but `syslog` has many logs written into. I think I have to disable this feature. Now I tried the below command to disable it:

```
dmesg -D
```

or this command:

```
sudo dmesg -n 1
```

But logs are written into syslog. How should I disable syslog logging, or to disable some services from writing into syslog?

Comment: You probably shouldn't disable syslog (completely) but instead you need to *tune the services* that use the syslog facility for logging to be less verbose if you don't want/need to log the events they are generating. How to do so depends on the actual services.

Comment: Most of it is about influxD database

Comment: Then I would suggest to read the logging section in the documentation on how to either reduce verbosity, or if for instance the product supports use of a **log file** instead of syslog.